# SQL Select Statement customer with two or more banks

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
CustomerID    CustomerName  Bank  Amount 
   1          Martin        BDO   Php 55.00 
   1          Martin        CBA   Php 150.00 
   2          Grace         BDO   Php 45.00
   2          Grace         BDO   Php 4100.00
   3          Blake         BPI   Php 120
```

I need a sql statement that will display customer with accounts on two different banks.

The result should be

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    Bank   Amount 
  1         Martin          BDO    Php 55.00 
  1         Martin          CBA    Php 150.00
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: "2 or more" is equal to "more than 1"

Comment: Don't store 'php'. Or, if you must, store it separately from amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to do this, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE customerID IN (
 SELECT customerID
 FROM customer
 GROUP BY customerID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Bank)) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways you can get the result that you want.  You could join on a subquery that gets a list of `CustomerIds` with more than one distinct `Bank`:

```
select 
  m1.CustomerId,
  m1.CustomerName,
  m1.Bank,
  m1.Amount
from mytable m1
inner join
(
  select 
    CustomerId
  from mytable
  group by CustomerId
  having count(distinct Bank) >= 2
) m2
  on m1.CustomerId = m2.CustomerId;
```

Or you could use a `WHERE EXISTS` to also get the result:

```
select 
  m.CustomerId,
  m.CustomerName,
  m.Bank,
  m.Amount
from mytable m
where exists (select 1
              from mytable m2
              where m.CustomerId = m2.CustomerId
                and m.Bank <> m2.Bank);
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4379a/6)